# Trying to change width of two divs when the first div is clicked

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, the first one has an initial width of 100% and the second one is hidden. Whne the user clicks on the first div, the second div should become visible and have the width of 35% and the first one should shrink to 65%.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
    <div class="big-width">
        <span> This div is the bigger of the two</span>
    </div>

    <div class="small-width">
        <span>This div is smaller</span>
    </div>
```

And my css:

```
.big-width{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    }
    
.small-width{
    display:none;
    width: 0%;
    }
    
.big-width:focus{
    width:65%;
    }
    
.big-width:focus ~ .small-width{
    display:flex;
    width:35%;
    }
```

I try clicking on the first div but nothing happens.

Comment: `div` is not an element that _can_ receive focus by default; you will need to add a [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) to make that work.

Comment: yes, this was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the div element a [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) so that it is focusable:

```css
.big-width {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
}
    
.small-width {
  display: none;
  width: 0%;
}
    
.big-width:focus {
  width: 65%;
}
    
.big-width:focus ~ .small-width {
  display: flex;
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-width" tabindex="0">
    <span> This div is the bigger of the two</span>
</div>

<div class="small-width">
    <span>This div is smaller</span>
</div>
```